# Loading large Size PDF on web form takes too much time

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iframe, response

We have a feature where we are trying to display PDF on web form. For that we have IFrame control on web form  and in code behind we have provided source to Iframe of another page where we are getting the data the we need to display in memory stream and then writing these data to page using Response.BinaryWrite() method. But this method is taking too much time while loading large size PDF e.g. 40 MB. Below is the code to write memory stream to page

```
using ( MemoryStream mStream = myData)
                {
                    if (mStream != null)
                    {
                        Byte[] bytes = mStream.ToArray();
                        Response.ClearHeaders();
                        Response.ClearContent();
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        Response.Expires = 0;
                        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                    }
                }
```

How can we improve performance in loading this large PDFs on web page?
Any suggestion on this would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the large PDFs are multiple pages, then one thing you could try would be to (re)save them as Linearized (AKA Web-Optimized) PDFs.  Linearized PDFs are structured so that all the information for rendering the first page to be displayed is downloaded first so that the rest of the document can be downloaded while the end-user is reading the first page.